# Does Java need to installed on all of the Remote Machine that's running Selenium Grid Nodes

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, powershell-2.0, selenium-grid

I have a hub running on one machine and i want to run the nodes on multiple other machines. Is that possible?

Example my hub is running on machine(SeleniumHub) using the command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub
```

Now i want to run my node on machine (SeleniumNode), I try using the command

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=\\SeleniumHub\Users\Administrator\\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://SeleniumHub:4444/grid/register -port 5001 -browser browserName="internet explorer"
```

But when i run the following command on the machine SeleniumNode, i get the error "java : The term 'java' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.".

Not sure if the error is showing is because java is not installed on the machine SeleniumNode or if its not the correct syntact on powershell.

I am running the script on powershell since cmd does not support UNC paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done few tests and yes you need Java install and configured on all the machines that are running the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2 node machines and not installed java in them, the only change is you need to give the absolute path of java while using java in command-

C:\Program File..\bin\java.exe
-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=\SeleniumHub\Users\Administrator\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://SeleniumHub:4444/grid/register -port 5001 -browser browserName="internet explorer"